# python regex finditer

Tags: python, regex

I have question about re, I tried to look answer on re documentary but I think I am to newbie for this.

I have string like this

```
string = "id=186 s_id=0  channel_name=[cspacer0]---BlaBla--- number=2"
```

I want to retrive all result after '=' so I used

```
re.finditer("=[\w]*", string)
```

My result was as follow

- 186
- 0
- empty space <-- there should be a [cspacer0]--BlaBla--
- 2

How should my pattern look to get the channel_name as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\w` token only matches word characters, to allow metacharacters I would use `\S` (any *non-white space* character) instead. Also, instead of `finditer` you can use `findall` for this task:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'id=186 s_id=0  channel_name=[cspacer0]---BlaBla--- number=2'
>>> re.findall(r'=(\S+)', s)
['186', '0', '[cspacer0]---BlaBla---', '2']
```

### EDIT

> The orginal string looks like this, I want to get everything starting with `=` skip `=ok` and `idx=0`

```
>>> s = 'error idx=0 msg=ok id=186 s_id=0 channel_name=[cspacer0]---BlaBla--- number=2'
>>> re.findall(r'(?<!idx)=(?!ok)(\S+)', s)
['186', '0', '[cspacer0]---BlaBla---', '2']
```

Comment: Yea, why only `=2`, in that case would you want to ignore `=0` as well? What's the rule for this?

Comment: I read trough my telnet data and found one more problem. Some of channels name have whitespace between. For example Yellow\sBall, and it only read Yellow with out Ball. Is there a chance to fix it somehow?

Comment: Sorry for asking for so much but there are mixes something like this Yellow\sBall, when I implemented your regex it printed me Yellow\Ball, and there are things like with multiple whitespaces Yellow\sBlack.\s\s\sHouse and it print them like Yellow\Black.\s\s\sHouse. Can it be fixed too? If this help the most sentex like this is only in channel_name=

Comment: You would need to use lookarounds: `re.findall(r'(?s)(?<!idx)=(?!ok)((?:(?!\s*\w+=).)*)', s)`

Comment: Thanks for the all info I will try to understand it now :) I were very helpful I hope I will learn that regex soon it looks really complicated!